# What does port ":http" mean in http.Server?

Tags: go

I was reading the type declaration for `http.Server` in the documentation and I came across this.

```
type Server struct {
    Addr string // TCP address to listen on, ":http" if empty
    // more...
}
```

If you call `srv.ListenAndServe()` and `srv.Addr` is an empty string, then `ListenAndServe` will pass `":http"` to `net.Listen` ([http/server.go](http://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=51082:51123#L1699)).

What does `":http"` mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes ports have aliases. `http` is 80.You can see more names here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Comment: Note: that was introduced in [commit 876e9d1b](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/876e9d1b89cf87f3791153fa9472142cd5294223#diff-21335be6bb7e87c8e655a237f635b095R679) in February 2011 by [Brad Fitzpatrick](https://github.com/bradfitz).